# VLOOKUP with an OR statement

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to get the following to work:

```
Dim cell As Range
For Each cell In Range("A3:A2000")

    If (Worksheets("n1").Range("AT" & cell.Row - 1) = _
        Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Range(AT & cell.Row - 1), _
        Worksheets("p1").Range("A1:E55000"), 5, False)) Or _
        (Worksheets("n1").Range("AT" & cell.Row - 1) = "N/A") Then

        [Do something]

    Else

        [do something else]

    End If

Next cell
```

Comment: Does that formula work on the worksheet? What would it look like on the worksheet? Is the *N/A* text that has been input or is it an actual `#N/A` worksheet error?

Answer (score 1):

The actual worksheet formula looks OK but you should guard against the dreaded `#N/A` no-match error when attempting a [VLOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-adceda66-30de-4f26-923b-7257939faa65) within VBA.

```
Dim cell As Range, wsP1 As Worksheet

Set wsP1 = Worksheets("p1")
With Worksheets("n1")
    For Each cell In .Range("A3:A2000")

        If Not IsError(.Range("AT" & cell.Row - 1)) And _
          Not IsError(Application.VLookup(.Range("AT" & cell.Row - 1), wsP1.Range("A:E"), 5, False)) Then
            If .Range("AT" & cell.Row - 1) = "N/A" Or _
              .Range("AT" & cell.Row - 1) = Application.VLookup(.Range("AT" & cell.Row - 1), wsP1.Range("A:E"), 5, False) Then

                [Do something]

            Else

                [do something else]

            End If

        Else
            cell = "there is a worksheet error"
            Debug.Print "there is a worksheet error"

        End If
    Next cell
End With
```

I've tightened up your code for readability  by assigning one worksheet to a variable and using a [With...End With statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx) for the other. You had at least two places where the *AT* column reference was not quoted.